# Delete row by identity number

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, delete-row

I've created a button to delete selected row from the database.

My problem is to delete the correct row. I want to delete the row which contains `231` in the identity column, even though its located as the first row of my DB.

```
myDataSet.Tables["myTable"].Rows[**here I want to address the identity nr from column 1.**].Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use the `DataTable.Select` method as described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) to get that one row you need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
string del = "DELETE From TableName Where ColumnName =@ColumnName";
        SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(del, strinconnection);
        a.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName", TheValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myDataSet.Tables["myTable"].Select("ID = 231").FirstOrDefault().Delete();
```

Be sure to have "using System.Linq;" at the top of the file.

Comment: Tryed to use this, but the row did not get deleted: OppdragDataSet.Tables["OppdragTable"].Select("ordreID = "+ordreID).FirstOrDefault().Delete();

Answer (score 0):

I tryed experimenting with the diffirent solutions, but here is the one that I managed to work. Im a beginner in programming overall, so maybe not the best solution, but it does what I want it to do.

```
SqlCeCommand myCmd = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE From myTable Where ordreID ="+myInt, myConnection); myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```